# Draw multiple objects with their textures in Vulkan

Tags: 3d, game-engine, vulkan

I want to draw a scene with multiple objects each with their own uniform buffer and textures, Currently I am able to draw multiple objects using Dynamic Uniform Buffer, The way i do it is that i iterate through the dynamic uniform buffer object offset and index of the vertices during command buffer recording, this way i am telling Vulkan to draw a Model using a specific global matrix, however i don't know how to bind texture information during this operation so that Vulkan knows to use the proper texture for that object, in my example I have four boxes with four different textures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So far i managed to draw multiple objects using the following methods:-

**NOTE: all vertex attribute information for all of the models are stored in one buffer which is organised on a per model basis.**

1.using one descriptor set with two bindings (one for UBOs & one for  the texture sampler), the type of the UBO is dynamic to accommodate the UBOs for all objects, during command buffer recording process your just iterate through the Dynamic UBO array corresponding to the specified vertex attributes to be drawn

**pros:** it is efficient and fast

**cons:** all objects will have the same texture (suitable for rendering the same model multiple times each with different ubo)

drawing process

```
for (uint32_t j = 0; j < m.geometryCount; j++)
    {
        uint32_t dynamicOffset =  j * 256;

        vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, pipelineLayout, 0, 1, &descriptorSet, 1, &dynamicOffset);
        vkCmdDraw(commandBuffers[i], m.vertexCount[j], 1, vertexCount, 0);

        vertexCount += m.vertexCount[j];
    }
```

2. using **(n)** number of descriptor sets for **(n)** number of models, each descriptor set with two binding ( one for UBO & one for the texture sampler), during the process of recording the command buffer you just bind the descriptor set corresponding to the specified vertex attributes to be drawn

**pros:** now each model has it's individual UBO and texture

**cons:** inefficient

Drawing process

```
for (uint32_t j = 0; j < m.geometryCount; j++)
    {

        VkDescriptorSet finalSet = descriptorSet[j];
        vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, pipelineLayout, 0, 1, &finalSet , 0, nullptr);
        vkCmdDraw(commandBuffers[i], m.vertexCount[j], 1, vertexCount, 0);

        vertexCount += m.vertexCount[j];
    }
```

There is another way which involves using push constants, in this method you arrange the UBO data for all of the models into one array and you create and bind a single descriptor set for that UBO array, from the vertex shader define an array variable for the incoming UBO data, then during drawing operation you send individual array indices using push constants. however i have not tested this method yet.

Comment: "cons: inefficient" -what is inefficient about that?

Answer (score 5):

You can use vkCmdBindDescriptorSets to bind the new texture.

Make sure the descriptor set with the texture binding is the highest numbered set in the layout.

When you call vkCmdBindDescriptorSets with firstset > 0 then the bound descriptor sets index `[0 ... firstSet-1]` will remain the same.

Comment: in my program example i record each object vertex information in a packed array and i keep track of number of vertices in another array, when i record draw commands i specify the specific vertex array and uniform buffer using iteration (that selects dynamic uniform offset as well as the index of the vertex array), how can i tell vulkan to use the correct texture for sampling for the different objects in the scene? lets say i  have 4 objects and 4 textures to sample from.

Comment: @BulBul: That is a very different question from the one you asked. You need to put such information in your actual question. And since changing dynamic uniform offsets requires calling `vkCmdBindDescriptorSets`, why not just apply the appropriate texture descriptor then?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas I edited my Question, kindly let me know if it is clear enough or not, so far i am using trial and error strategy, last time i tried to draw multiple objects using vkCmdBindDescriptorSets using normal uniform buffer objects (for each object i bound a different descriptors of uniform buffer), all my 3D models ended up using the last bound uniform buffer set it was a mess, so will this method work for textures?

Comment: @BulBul it's bad form to move the goal posts after you have received an answer. Instead use the new information to make a better more directed question.

Comment: @ratchet freak the post is technically the same, i just removed some parts that might lead to confusion and added more details